# Use explicitly alias in shell with docker command

Tags: bash, shell, docker, alias

I have an alias in my .bashrc that is:

```
alias ansible-galaxy='sudo docker run --rm -it -v $PWD:/app  myregistry.com/ansible-galaxy:2.1.0.0'
```

In my shell, I must do:

```
ansible-galaxy -c -r -f galaxy.yml
```

Is it posible to write the full command in a term ?

It seems that if I execute

```
sudo docker run --rm -it -v $PWD:/app  myregistry.com/ansible-galaxy:2.1.0.0 -c -r -f galaxy.yml
```

it goes in docker container and don't find anymore the galaxy.yml that is in the docker host. Any idea how should I fix it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are mounting present working directory on /app folder inside container `-v $PWD:/app`

Try running this `ansible-galaxy -c -r -f /app/galaxy.yml` since your galaxy.yml is in $PWD, it should be available in /app folder inside container.

Comment: It is weird. I accepted you answer because it reponds the question, but I found out it is working when I execute it in my local terminal, but it fails when I execute it from my jenkins docker container....

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro it will work in local terminal since you are running the command from same directory where galaxy.yml is located. About running it from jenkins docker container, you need galaxy.yml mounted inside the container.